# intel turbo boost driver requirements

Tags: cpu, intel

Is it necessary to use *intel_pstate* driver to enable intel turbo boost technology? I have a processor using acpi-cpufreq driver, when I execute

```
cpupower frequency-info
```

the upper limit of *hardware limits* is the standard cpu operating frequency, not the max turbo frequency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turbo boost doesn't require software intervention but it can be disabled (by the BIOS/UEFI or by the OS).
When disabled it is not reported by the `cpuid` instruction.

You can check  if TB is enabled by executing the command:

```
cpuid -1l6 | grep -i turbo
```

You'll need to install the *cpuid* tool but this doesn't require the `intel_pstate` driver.

If TB is not enabled, check your BIOS/UEFI configuration. The OS could disable it too but it's not done by the Linux Kernel, eventually check your services.

---

Even if Turbo is enabled it can be limited, I don't think this is done by Linux but to be sure you can check the MSR `0x1ad`:

```
rdmsr 0x1ad
```

You need to be root to execute this (and install *rdmsr*).
It will give you an hex number where each byte is the multiplier to apply to the base frequency to get the maximum turbo frequency.
The rightmost byte tells the max TB frequency when only one core is active (assuming a reasonable configuration).
In my case I get `27272727`, the right most byte (the last two hex digits) is `27` or 39 in decimal.
The base frequency is usually 100MHz so I get 39*100MHz = 3,9GHz.

This MSR can be written by the software in some CPU.
Check if the frequency you got is the one advertised.

---

If TB is enabled and the maximum frequency is as advertised than you are fine.
The ACPI driver is probably not including the TB frequency in its maximum frequency but since the TB technology is active the CPU will use it autonomously.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I figure out the reason why I get nearly no frequency improvement is that  my boot parameters contains 'processor.max_cstate=1 intel_idel.max_cstate' which keeps all cores active. With all cores active, turbo boost can't do much to increase cpu frequency.

Comment: @RobertLi Out of curiosity, who set those boot parameters?

Comment: Probably the linux distribution vendor, ubuntu. There is a bug that the kernel doesn't support some deeper idle cstates, if not restrict the available cstates, the system would crash or freeze. Check this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/883430/will-the-intel-bay-trail-cpu-problem-be-fixed-in-17-04?newreg=25c767f2a153401dbff727d72b386bed